# How do I enable SSH within AMI Megarac?

Tags: ipmi

My server has an ASRock Rack motherboard that comes with a dedicated AMI Megarac IPMI SoC. There appears to be little documentation available for AMI Megarac and I suspect that this is because they intend you to have a support contract with a re-seller; I do not.

I'm trying to set up SSH access, I have enabled the SSH service within the GUI and have uploaded my public SSH key to my IPMI account; I know the key works as I use it elsewhere.

When I attempt an SSH connection to the BMC, it stalls for 30 seconds and then asks for a password. The password I would normally use with the account to sign into the GUI, does not work either.

What is the correct way to set this up?

As advised in the very brief manual that came with the board, the key is in pub format.